# How to build an architecture of any Programming Project?

Tags: php, architecture

I am a PHP Programmer and willing design my own architecture to work on please suggest me what do i need to design the architecture for any project in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the most important thing are the requirements i.e. without requirements you cannot do anything. So, it is quite difficult to answer your question the way it is.

Some Pointers from my side are:

1. Get all the functional requirements clear. (i.e. what is your software intended to do?)
2. Then decide and who all will be the users
3. Depending upon the users and environment, chart down non-functional requirements like performance, size, internationalization etc

Once you are clear with these things, you can categorize your software like Gaming Software, Utility Library, Compiler etc. Once you are at this stage, if you post a query or search in google, you'll find plenty of help.

All the Best. : )